# Cannot login as guest or create new user

Tags: login, users

I can't login as a guest. The screen goes to the black screen with blinking cursor for a second then straight back to login scree.

I can still log in as myself (administrator) and tried to create a new user. this failed too giving me the following message:

```
running '/usr/sbin/adduser' failed: /usr/sbin/adduser returned an error (1): useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
adduser: `/usr/sbin/useradd -d /home/joe -g joe -s /bin/bash -u 1001 joe' returned error code 1. Exiting.
```

Any help much appreciated. 
I am running Ubuntu 11.10 on a netbook.

Thanks
Matt

Comment: I would post the output of `cat /etc/passwd` first to see if there's some obvious error. Before I went to copying someone else's /etc/shadow anyway.  I would also `sudo apt-get install lsof` and `lsof /etc/passwd`

Comment: I removed `/etc/*.lock` and the problem seemed to have been solved. I'm not sure why `/etc/*.lock` are there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that your /etc/passwd is not corrupted. If it is, replace it with a new file:
I have provided a test-user known as testuser, the password is testtest for this temp user.
Be sure to give change the testuser home directory to your home directory. I have bolded the location where you need to change the home directory. Leave everything else as is. Be sure to change these files as root and have a backup.
Here is a clean /etc/shadow:

```
er wr root:!:15438:0:99999:7:::
daemon:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
bin:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
sys:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
sync:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
games:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
man:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
lp:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
mail:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
news:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
uucp:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
proxy:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
www-data:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
backup:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
list:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
irc:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
gnats:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
nobody:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
libuuid:!:15259:0:99999:7:::
syslog:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
colord:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
messagebus:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
lightdm:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
avahi-autoipd:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
avahi:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
usbmux:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
kernoops:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
pulse:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
rtkit:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
speech-dispatcher:!:15259:0:99999:7:::
hplip:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
saned:*:15259:0:99999:7:::
internetu::15439:0:99999:7:::
boinc:*:15440:0:99999:7:::
radvd:*:15442:0:99999:7:::
ntp:*:15442:0:99999:7:::
testuser:$6$sd3pG/1b$9mnB638HBFC8pMcNuftmwXYaV.omf.aPd6QubiGVtFPKRUMOTi5pKuaXlHgqVJKAZPjphUwsV8vUpLIAiVTNj/:15447:0:99999:7:::
```

And here is /etc/passwd

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/sh
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/sh
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/bin/sh
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/bin/sh
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/bin/sh
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/bin/sh
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/bin/sh
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/bin/sh
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/bin/sh
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/sh
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/bin/sh
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/bin/sh
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/bin/sh
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/bin/sh
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/bin/sh
libuuid:x:100:101::/var/lib/libuuid:/bin/sh
syslog:x:101:103::/home/syslog:/bin/false
colord:x:102:105:colord colour management daemon,,,:/var/lib/colord:/bin/false
messagebus:x:103:107::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
lightdm:x:104:108:Light Display Manager:/var/lib/lightdm:/bin/false
avahi-autoipd:x:105:112:Avahi autoip daemon,,,:/var/lib/avahi-autoipd:/bin/false
avahi:x:106:113:Avahi mDNS daemon,,,:/var/run/avahi-daemon:/bin/false
usbmux:x:107:46:usbmux daemon,,,:/home/usbmux:/bin/false
kernoops:x:108:65534:Kernel Oops Tracking Daemon,,,:/:/bin/false
pulse:x:109:119:PulseAudio daemon,,,:/var/run/pulse:/bin/false
rtkit:x:110:122:RealtimeKit,,,:/proc:/bin/false
speech-dispatcher:x:111:29:Speech Dispatcher,,,:/var/run/speech-dispatcher:/bin/sh
hplip:x:112:7:HPLIP system user,,,:/var/run/hplip:/bin/false
saned:x:113:123::/home/saned:/bin/false
internetu:x:1002:1002:Internet user,,,:/home/internetu:/bin/bash
boinc:x:114:125:BOINC core client,,,:/var/lib/boinc-client:/bin/false
radvd:x:115:65534::/var/run/radvd:/bin/false
ntp:x:116:126::/home/ntp:/bin/false
testuser:x:1001:1001:testuser,,,,:/home/***CHANGE THIS TO YOUR OLD HOMEFOLDER***:/bin/bash
```